# count number of Null variables per row mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, null

We have the following table in Mysql using innoDB:

```
id   Var1   Var2  Var 3     
1    NULL    1     2   
2    2    NULL    NULL  
3    4       2    NULL
```

We pretend to produce Var4 with the number of NULL variables per row:

```
id Var4  
1    1  
2    2  
3    1
```

I tried unsuccessfully :

```
update db.table 
set var4 = ISNULL(var1) + ISNULL(var2) + ISNULL(var3);
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you updating the table? Because now it looks like you're trying to save a calculated field in your database. And that would be against the rules of Database Normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select id, ((var1 is null) + (var2 is null) + (var3 is null)) as var4
from table t;
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers, with true being `1` and false being `0`.  You can just add them up to get the total.

As an update:

```
update table t
    set var4 = ((var1 is null) + (var2 is null) + (var3 is null));
```

As a note, MySQL doesn't support `ISNULL()`.  That is more of a SQL Server function.  But it is not ANSI standard anyway, so you are usually better off using `coalesce()`.