# Calculate the percentage of filled columns per row

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the number of filled columns per row. For example the the column Perc is the value I wish to calculate.

```
id   Col1   Col2  Col3  Perc 
1    NULL   1     2     75%   #3 out of 4
2    2      NULL  NULL  50%   #2 out of 4  
3    NULL   NUll  NULL  25%   #1 out of 4
4    a      Yes   No    100%  #4 out of 4
```

I read [count number of Null variables per row mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700613/count-number-of-null-variables-per-row-mysql), wich offers a possible solution. However in my case the column names and number change frequently. So i would like a more robust query which does not have to be altered every time the names or column count changes.

Comment: Look again at normalisation

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,item_id INT NOT NULL
,value VARCHAR(12) NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,item_id)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,NULL),
(1,2,'1'),
(1,3,'2'),
(2,1,'2'),
(2,2,NULL),
(2,3,NULL),
(3,1,NULL),
(3,2,NULL),
(3,3,NULL),
(4,1,'a'),
(4,2,'Yes'),
(4,3,'No');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+---------+-------+
| id | item_id | value |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | NULL  |
|  1 |       2 | 1     |
|  1 |       3 | 2     |
|  2 |       1 | 2     |
|  2 |       2 | NULL  |
|  2 |       3 | NULL  |
|  3 |       1 | NULL  |
|  3 |       2 | NULL  |
|  3 |       3 | NULL  |
|  4 |       1 | a     |
|  4 |       2 | Yes   |
|  4 |       3 | No    |
+----+---------+-------+

SELECT x.id
     , ROUND((COUNT(value)+1)/(COUNT(*)+1)*100,2) pct 
  FROM my_table x 
 GROUP 
    BY id;
+----+--------+
| id | pct    |
+----+--------+
|  1 |  75.00 |
|  2 |  50.00 |
|  3 |  25.00 |
|  4 | 100.00 |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: As far as i can tell this query need to be altered if the number of columns change or if a  column name changes, which i am trying to avoid. Futhermore in my case every row is unique.

Comment: @Nebu The beauty of this design is precisely that it doesn't (as opposed to yours which does)! In this design, columns never need to be added, only rows. In my case, every row is unique too - hence the PRIMARY KEY on (id,item_id). This is called normalisation.

Comment: Yes i see now what you are trying to do. This could work well if i use temporary tables. But how do i program the INSERT INTO my_table VALUES from my own table without having to specify the rows and columns?

Comment: How do i populate the my_table from my own table.

Comment: Well, my_table supersedes your table. To create it in the first place you can use a series of UNIONs. If it's not obvious how that would work, I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm, this would result in a design change of the table structure. Although this would work it is not what i am looking for. The table structure is fixed. I can create temporary tables. So creating this new table my_table could be done in a transaction wich calculated the percentage at the end and then drops the my_table table. But the query that creates the my_table should be populated from the data table with an unkown number of colums. More info on how to accomplish this is very welcome.

Comment: If you can 'add columns' then the table structure is not fixed, and is instead a poor design. I would suggest you seriously rethink that approach. One way or another, the columns should be fixed (barring unforseen amendments further down the road)