# How to count null values in per row in mysql? İs it possible

Tags: mysql, count, row

I want to count null values in mysql per row.

```
id a    b    c    d     missing_count
 1 a    b    null null  2
 2 null b    c    d     1
 3 null null null d     3
```

Comment: the image of the table above

Comment: ISNULL will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700613/count-number-of-null-variables-per-row-mysql

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic if poor design, but without a more properly representative data set, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL query can be used to get the number of null values in each row:

```
SELECT id, ISNULL(A) + ISNULL(B) + ISNULL(C) + ISNULL(D) as MissingCount FROM table_name
```

See documentation for [ISNULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_isnull.asp)